# Record sound and save using AS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash, mxml

How to record sound from a microphone and save it from the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.SampleDataEvent; 
        import flash.media.Microphone;
        import flash.net.FileReference;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import flash.net.FileReference;


        [Bindable] private var microphoneList:Array;
        protected var microphone:Microphone;
        protected var isRecording:Boolean = false;
        protected function setupMicrophoneList():void
        { 
            microphoneList = Microphone.names; 
        } 
        protected function setupMicrophone():void 
        {       
            microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(comboMicList.selectedIndex);
        } 
        protected function startMicRecording():void 
        { 
            Alert.show("In recording");
            isRecording = true;
            Alert.show("In recording1");
            microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
            Alert.show("In recording22");
        }
        protected function stopMicRecording():void 
        { 
            isRecording = false;
            microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
        } 
        private function gotMicData(micData:SampleDataEvent):void 
        { 
            Alert.show("In mic data");
            // micData.data contains a ByteArray with our sample. }
            try{
            var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
            file.save(micData.data ,"Testsound.flv");
            }
            catch(e:Error)
            {
                Alert.show("In gotomicdataexception"+e);
            }
        }

        ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:ComboBox x="150" id="comboMicList" dataProvider="{microphoneList}" />
<mx:Button x="250" id="startmicrec" label="Start Rec" click="startMicRecording()"/>
<mx:Button x="350" id="stopmicrec" label="Stop Rec" click="stopMicRecording()"/> 
<mx:Button x="50" id="setupmic" label="Select Mic" click="setupMicrophone()"/>
<mx:Button x="450" id="playrecsound" label="Play sound" click="playbackData()"/>
```

Comment: Don't know encoder to save sound byteArray to flv, but there is micRecord library (http://code.google.com/p/micrecorder/) which has wav encoder. Try this out.

Comment: @Art:My question is mostly regarding the saving  the file rather than the format.How can i save the file after recording it..

Comment: @Rajeev Generally it is not considered good etiquette to post three version of the same question over the course of two days.

Comment: @Rajeev: You don't need to launch file.save on every SampleDataEvent, you just have to store all data and then get resulting byteArray after stopping recording. But first read how to handle SampleDataEvent data http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adobe record sound and save](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427518/adobe-record-sound-and-save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your updated code that will provide you ability to save file after recording it. But anyway you need to encode bytearray into format like wav or mp3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="this_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;


            [Bindable] private var microphoneList:Array;
            protected var microphone:Microphone;
            protected var isRecording:Boolean = false;
            private var soundBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            protected function setupMicrophoneList():void
            { 
                microphoneList = Microphone.names; 
            } 
            protected function setupMicrophone():void 
            {       
                microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(comboMicList.selectedIndex);
            } 
            protected function startMicRecording():void 
            { 
                trace("In recording");
                isRecording = true;
                trace("In recording1");
                microphone.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
                trace("In recording22");
            }
            protected function stopMicRecording():void 
            { 
                isRecording = false;
                microphone.removeEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, gotMicData);
                saveMicData();
            } 

            private function saveMicData():void
            {
                trace("In mic data");
                // micData.data contains a ByteArray with our sample. }
                try{
                    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();

                    file.save(/*You need encoded soundBytes here*/soundBytes ,"Testsound.wav");
                }
                catch(e:Error)
                {
                    trace("In gotomicdataexception"+e);
                }
            }

            private function gotMicData(event:SampleDataEvent):void 
            { 
                while(event.data.bytesAvailable)
                {
                    var sample:Number = event.data.readFloat();
                    soundBytes.writeFloat(sample);
                }
            }

            private function playbackData():void
            {

            }

            protected function this_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                setupMicrophoneList();
            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <mx:ComboBox id="comboMicList" dataProvider="{microphoneList}" />
    <mx:Button id="setupmic" label="Select Mic" click="setupMicrophone()"/>
    <s:HGroup>
        <mx:Button id="startmicrec" label="Start Rec" click="startMicRecording()"/>
        <mx:Button id="stopmicrec" label="Stop Rec" click="stopMicRecording()"/> 
        <!--<mx:Button id="playrecsound" label="Play sound" click="playbackData()"/>-->
    </s:HGroup>
</s:Application>
```