# AS3 audiioencoder to convert to audio

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, flash, mxmlc

In action script how to convert using audio encoder a recorded byte array from microphone to MP3

```
     public var recordedData:ByteArray;          
     recordedData.writeBytes(sample.data, 0, sample.data.bytesAvailable);
```

How to save recordedData to mp3 using audio encoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find yourself an MP3 encoding library that runs in the Flash player.  A simple google search finds [Shine](https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy) to be pretty popular.  Another option is to stream the audio up to the server and encode there.

Depending on your environment, you might be able to use something like [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) if you are in Air and are willing to build a native extension to do the encoding.

**EDIT**

If you are using Shine, I found an [example in the project](https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy/blob/master/src/fr/kikko/test/ShineMP3EncoderTest.as) that implies that encoding is easy:

```
private var mp3Encoder:ShineMP3Encoder;

private function encodeClicked(event:Event):void {
    mp3Encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(wavLoader.data);
    mp3Encoder.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mp3EncodeComplete);
    mp3Encoder.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, mp3EncodeProgress);
    mp3Encoder.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, mp3EncodeError);
    mp3Encoder.start();
}

private function saveClicked(event : MouseEvent) : void {
    mp3Encoder.saveAs();
}
```

Comment: @Rajeev Not that I am aware of.  But Shine uses Alchemy which is a C/C++ compiler for Actionscript Byte Code (ABC) which gives you a library which you can call from AS3... so that is all you really need.

Comment: \\@Brian Genisio:I m actually trying to build an APP like this http://www.jordansthings.com/blog/?p=5.If you can help me do this using AS and flex it would be helpful

Comment: @Rajeev So, that app is using Shine as well.  What problem are you running into?  Just because Shine is C/C++ doesn't mean you can't use it.  Simply download the [SWC](https://github.com/kikko/Shine-MP3-Encoder-on-AS3-Alchemy/tree/master/bin) and put it in your libs folder.  You can use it in Flex/AS3.

Comment: \\@Brian Genisio:u had answered my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427518/adobe-record-sound-and-save .I am using Flash builder on windows.Even if you could answer the older question with edits..i will use ur suggestions.

Comment: @Rajeev You'd use it like any other SWC library.  Just `new` up an instance of `ShineMP3Encoder` and work against it.  I updated my answer to show some example code...