# as3 decode mp3 into raw sound data

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, mp3

My function for `sound` object plays byteArray data via `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA` handler.

It normally plays `byteArray` data taken from a mike, but mp3 file should be decoded to be played. How to 'convert' mp3 file data into byteArray with a raw sound, which can be played by `sound`'s `SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA`?

flash player is v10, `loadCompressedDataFromByteArray()` doesn't work.

Comment: Standard Sound class allows to load and play MP3 audio. Is it not a viable option?

Comment: there is a weird way to `sound.play` the mp3 sound, then take `computeSpectrum` data and feed it into a `SampleDataEvent` handler

Comment: @Organis I have only mp3's bynary data, nothing like remote url or something like that.

Comment: @elDude Oh. I see. How about this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448179/as3-audiioencoder-to-convert-to-audio

Comment: There's a question `how to encode audio into mp3` in that thread. I need the opposite thing.

Comment: Why can't you update FP?